# How to sanely handle conditional TS class mixins

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, mixins

My use case is that I have 1 base class that all of these mixins will be for, and they need to be omitted or applied based on a set of object properties that corresponds to the base class

```
interface Thing {
  hasColour: boolean,
  hasShape: boolean,
  hasSmell: boolean
}

class ThingBase {
  constructor(thing: Thing) {}
}

function Colourable(Base: ThingBase) {
  return class Colourable extends Base {
    constructor(thing: Thing) {}

    getColour(): string {}
  }
}

function Shapeable(Base: ThingBase) {
  return class Shapeable extends Base {
    constructor(thing: Thing) {}

    getShape(): string {}
  }
}

function Smellable(Base: ThingBase) {
  return class Smellable extends Base {
    constructor(thing: Thing) {}

    getSmell(): string {}
  }
}
```

So I've got this working but the problem is that there's 8 combinations of these mixins right? And if I add a new one there's 16 etc. So I need to create these classes dynamically at the time of instantiation? I can use something like what the TS docs link to is doing:

```
let mix = (superclass) => new MixinBuilder(superclass);

class MixinBuilder {
  constructor(superclass) {
    this.superclass = superclass;
  }

  with(...mixins) { 
    return mixins.reduce((c, mixin) => mixin(c), this.superclass);
  }
}
```

But then how do I do instanceof elsewhere in the code? Do I rebuild the dynamic class every time I want to check the instance type?

```
const mixins: ((base: ThingBase) => ThingBase)[] = []
const thing = {
  hasColour: true,
  hasShape: true,
  hasSmell: true,
}

thing.hasColour && mixins.push(Colourable);
thing.hasShape && mixins.push(Shapeable);
thing.hasSmell && mixins.push(Smellable);

const ThingClass = mix(ThingBase).with(...mixins)
const thingClassInstance = new ThingClass(thing);

console.log(thingClassInstance instanceof ???)
```

This is a very contrived example since I need to do these checks across the system and not just in the same scope. Is there a better way to build these classes/refer back to what I created? Should I just keep an exponentially growing library of them pre-built so that I can always statically check the instance type?

Edit: [I've made a codesandbox repro](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-cdn-ve0mrs?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code so it's a self-contained [mre] others can drop into a standalone IDE and see what you're seeing.  Right now it's pseudocode/abridged and the `mix()` function isn't defined (an external link isn't sufficient for a definition; all relevant code should be included as plaintext in the question itself).  It's also not clear to me why you want to do `instanceof`; could you show the use case where it matters?  Perhaps you could use a different type guard instead, but without a [mre] it's hard to know how to advise.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it an update. I want to do `instanceof` so that I can satisfy the compiler that my class instance has the `getShape` method for example. For now I may just write a type guard for each mixin as you suggest. It's a bit more manual but it's cleaner than pre-mixing every combination

Comment: Did you test your update in an IDE?  I'm seeing [all kinds of errors](https://tsplay.dev/NrDQVW) most of which are unrelated to your question.  If you make it easy for others to work on it, there's more of a chance that they will do so.

Comment: I've added a repro to the question. It pretty closely mirrors what I have in my codebase. The issue may be the types I've already made honestly, I was trying to follow [the ts mixin docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#handbook-content) but may have been unsuccessful

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mM8z6N) meet your needs?  The idea is to declare optional methods on the base class so that the compiler is aware of what you're trying to test.  Then instead of `if (x instanceof ???)` you write `if (x.getShape)` and everything works as expected.  If that works for you I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'd like for the base class to not be aware of every possible mixin since in my actual code that would spiral out of control. [I think I have an answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-cdn-ve0mrs?file=/src/index.ts) that I was able to scrounge up

Comment: Your own example has the constructor take a `Thing` which apparently knows about every possible mixin; do you want to change the example so that the base is more agnostic about what it's receiving? Looking at your answer: I'm not sure how writing one type guard function per mixin is particularly better than one optional method per mixin; could you clarify?

Comment: 1/2 ... This is another example of how the concept of mixins is not understood. Mixins are there for providing additional behavior on a _"has a"_ basis whereas classes and sub-classing always assures an _"is a"_ relationship, hence inheritance. The effort for attempting the coverage of all possible behavior combinations by dynamically creating all necessary classes just proves that mixin-based composition and class-based extension are two different concepts. Trying to emulate one with the other leads to code like presented by the OP, even more since it has to be done in TypeScript where one...

Comment: 2/2 ...has to satisfy a preprocessing type-checking task which is based on type-annotations and static code-analysis. So called _"class-based mixins"_ regardless of which flavor in TS show the limitation of the latter. I personally like TS and use it where it does not start limiting the writing of expressive code in a painful way. For what I consider edge cases, like the above presented, I prefer to fall back on pure JS backed by properly implemented unit test. And the latter from my experience are more reliable than what a so called _compiler_ that only exists in the dev-environment suggests.